# Recover Windows from safe mode on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a google cloud server with windows installed on it, yesterday I rebooted it into safe mode but I forgot to check "networking" option and now I cant connect to it. How can I exit from safe mode from google console? 
thanks

Comment: Usually Windows starts the normal mode by default if no error occurred on the previous startup. I'd just try to reboot the machine.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I rebooted several times. And I cant connect to it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the serial port console of your instance with this command in the cloud shell:

```
$ gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME]
--metadata=serial-port-enable=1
```

Then after connect to your instance from the serial port:

```
$ gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port [INSTANCE_NAME] --port=2
```

After you enter the windows SAC, you can enter to a CMD session, it prompts you to use your user and password:

```
cmd
ch -sn cmd0001
```

In case you forgot the password,you can generate a new one;

```
$ gcloud beta compute reset-windows-password [INSTANCE-NAME]
```

Once inside you can stop the safe mode boot and log normal launching:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot
```

And finaly shutdown/start your instance.