# Can't connect to Windows VM after booting into safe mode

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines, rdp, safe-mode

I cannot connect to my windows VM after booting into safe mode [networking enabled]. I have restarted, and I have tried using the serial console but it doesn't make much sense to me. I am trying to figure out:

A. How to enable RDP on Windows via the GCP console

B. How to restart the computer in normal mode via GCP console.

Please help.

EDIT: Solved it myself lol. See my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps in this guide worked for me.

[Recover Windows from safe mode on Google Cloud Platform](https://serverfault.com/questions/907488/recover-windows-from-safe-mode-on-google-cloud-platform)

I feel so much better now haha.

P.S. when entering credentials to log in, I just used "." as the domain.